# Bayesin network structure learning python package for continuous variables

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-networks, probabilistic-programming

I have been looking for a python package for Bayesian network structure learning for continuous variables. I have been using Pomegranate, but that seems to work only for continuous variables.

Comment: I think you meant that Pomegranate only works for Discrete variables. Have you checked out PyAgrum? It's been on my list of packages to explore, but alas I haven't had a chance yet, so I can't speak from experience. Nevertheless, the docs look good.  https://pyagrum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/BNLearning.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the `pgmpy` library. It contains many functionalities, including modeling of continuous and discrete variables.

edit: continuous learning is not supported yet. https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy/issues/772